# How can I access window.document object from ActiveXObject?

Tags: c#, javascript, com-interop

How can I access window.document object from ActiveXObject in InternetExplorer?
I'm using C# language for my ActiveXObject.

Thanks
Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the object being instantiated wouldn't know - from where it is being called.
So, in order to use window.document inside the ActiveXObject, you will have to pass the instance of window.document as a property.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems the object should know where its being called, because in recent past UserControl.Parent.Script was reffered to DOM model, but it no longer supported...